# Replace C function and mark the older as error/deprecated

Tags: c, gcc

The question is a bit tricky but it is quite simple.

Have a shared code in C, and I would like to "ban" some function (typically `system()`). There will be a replacement function  (eg. `my_system()`). This replacement function will use the original function but with integrated checks.

I have made some research and find the keyword `poison`:

```
#pragma GCC poison system
```

And I can declare my custom function before the pragma:

```
int my_system (const char *line){
    ...
    system(line_ok);
    ...
}
```

Is it the right way to proceed?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you declare a function in respect to a pragma (i.e., before or after it). The pragma will always be preprocessed before the function is compiled.

Comment: According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html your solution should work. Of course you must make sure that you use the pragma everywhere.

Comment: @goodvibration I think you're wrong: "Sometimes, there is an identifier that you want to remove completely from your program, and make sure that it never creeps back in. To enforce this, you can poison the identifier with this pragma. #pragma GCC poison is followed by a list of identifiers to poison. If any of those identifiers appears anywhere in the source after the directive, it is a hard error."

Comment: Using `#pragma GCC poison` is okay as long as you accept that it is only guaranteed to work with gcc.   Other compilers are not required to respond to that pragma.    If some developers modify your code to use `system()`, the code will sail past other compilers.   If that happens a lot, someone - possibly you - will get an unpleasant surprise - and potentially several unpleasant surprises - when porting ostensibly working code back to gcc.